# Rational Solution Set to these equations and inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I have this system that I have to solve (or disprove that it exists), and I put it in Wolfram, and have little help. I don't know where to start.

Let $a,b,c,$ and $d$ be ***positive rational*** numbers such that

$a>1$

$b>\sqrt{a^2-1}$

$c=\sqrt{-a^2+b^2+2}$

$d=\sqrt{b^2+1}$

Find $a,b,c,$ and $d$ or prove that there is no such $a,b,c,$ and $d$ that exist.

EDIT: I found a way to prove that both $b$ and $d$ cannot be integers, but I still don't know about the rational thing. The integer fact is pretty simple, just that positive squares cannot be one apart. However, obviously rational squares can be one apart, so it doesn't help much with the proof.

Also, another trivial fact, that $b=\sqrt{a^2+c^2-2}.$

Comment: Are you interested in all possible solutions or just to show the solution set is nonempty? $(a, b, c, d)=(1, 3/4, 5/4, 5/4)$ is a valid solution.

Comment: sorry, i will edit the question, but i meant to put strictly greater signs for the first 2 inequalities. In which case this solution wouldn't work

Comment: i got confused with the formatting